# Azure service bus - how to add metadata to the message

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using .net core web app as the publisher and .net core console app as subscriber. 
I am able to successfully pass messages between these two systems using Managed Identities - set up in Azure portal.

My question is I need to add metadata to the the message that is being sent. How do I do that ?

Below is my publisher code :

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payloadEvents);
Message message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider();

TopicClient sendClient = new TopicClient(_serviceBusNamespace, _topicName, tokenProvider, retryPolicy: null);

await sendClient.SendAsync(message);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Message`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message?view=azure-dotnet) object has a property called [`UserProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.userproperties?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_Message_UserProperties) that can be used to set custom metadata for that message.

Something like:

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payloadEvents);
Message message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
message.UserProperties.Add("key1", "value1");
message.UserProperties.Add("key2", "value2");

var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider();

TopicClient sendClient = new TopicClient(_serviceBusNamespace, _topicName, tokenProvider, retryPolicy: null);

await sendClient.SendAsync(message);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) One more question will this custom metadata be accessible to the filter rules ? Since message content will not be accessible by the filter rules.

Comment: The answer is yes. Basically you would need to define `SQL Filters`. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters (read section about SQL Filters).

Answer (score 0):

[`UserProperties` were renamed to `ApplicationProperties` in 7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876086/how-do-i-add-a-custom-property-using-the-azure-messaging-servicebus-library)

Here's how I do it for sending/receiving on a queue, with a function queue trigger.

Send with metadata:

```
var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
var sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);
var serviceBusMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(body);

serviceBusMessage.ApplicationProperties["key1"] = "value1";
serviceBusMessage.ApplicationProperties["key2"] = "value2";

await sender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage);
```

Receive metadata:

```
[FunctionName(MyQueueReceiver)]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(MyQueueName, Connection = ConnectionString)] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ILogger log)
{
    var key1 = message.ApplicationProperties["key1"] as string;

    // Do something with message.Body
}
```

Versions:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.13.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
```

Note `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` only exists in `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` 5.x, and currently 4.x is installed by default in a new function project (at least for me).