# How do I add a custom property using the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus library?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

the latest sdk [(Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.0.1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#choosing-the-appropriate-service-bus-net-sdk) doesn't seem to have the option to add custom(user) properties to a message (ie: for filtering topic subs). Has anyone found out how to do this now? [SendMessageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage?view=azure-dotnet)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was replaced by [ServiceBusMessage.ApplicationProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage.applicationproperties?view=azure-dotnet):

> In v7, the userProperties and label on the message were renamed to applicationProperties and subject to be in sync with the AMQP spec. We did this across languages as part of our new SDKs.
>
> We realize that we should have done a better job at communicating this
> in our migration guide which is linked from the readme for the package
> in npm and github as well as from our changelog. We will do so
> immediately.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/12861#issuecomment-743406738

Answer (score 17):

Adding on to @David's answer.
This property is read-only hence **you can't simply write:**

```
message.ApplicationProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

In order to add your custom properties in this dictionary use:

```
ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(content);
message.ApplicationProperties.Add("yourKey", "yourValue");
```

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/TopicFilters/Program.cs) official GitHub documentation for further details around topic filtering.