# Azure service bus topic user defined properties

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

This article explains about various filters that can be used on the service bus topic:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters

I am interested in using the "user-defined properties" discussed on that page. How do we set those properties when using [ServiceBusMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage?view=azure-dotnet) class to set the message and then send it using [ServiceBusSender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussender?view=azure-dotnet) class?

Comment: Add your custom properties to [`ServiceBusMessage.ApplicationProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage.applicationproperties?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_ServiceBusMessage_ApplicationProperties) before you send the message from your publisher, and read them when you receive the message in your consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Andrew Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2363967/andrew-williamson) for your suggestion ,converting this as to answer to help other community members.

"Add your custom properties to [`ServiceBusMessage.ApplicationProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage.applicationproperties?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_ServiceBusMessage_ApplicationProperties) before you send the message from your publisher, and read them when you receive the message in your consumer".

Also as mentioned in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/12861#issuecomment-743406738) .

> In v7, the `userProperties` and label on the message were renamed to
> **`applicationProperties`** and subject to be in sync with the AMQP spec. We
> did this across languages as part of our new SDKs.
>
> We realize that we should have done a better job at communicating this
> in our migration guide which is linked from the readme for the package
> in npm and github as well as from our changelog. We will do so
> immediately.

For more information please refer this SO THREAD :  [How do I add a custom property using the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876086/how-do-i-add-a-custom-property-using-the-azure-messaging-servicebus-library)